# BI Publisher - Parameters between the dates

Tags: sql, date, parameters, bi-publisher

In BI-PUBLISHER, I have two parameters of `STARTDATE` and `ENDDATE`.

There is a field in the table `ACTIVE_DATE` which would be used in the above parameters.

I am using the following condition in the query:

```
trunc(active_date) between NVL(:P_Active_Date, trunc(active_date))
and NVL(:P_Close_Date, trunc(active_date)
```

If both the parameters are null, it should select all ranges of the dates.

But when I apply these parameters, it doesn't show me the correct result.
Even when I select both the parameters, it still doesn't show me the correct result.

How should it be done?

Comment: Try changing in the NVL'S active_date to 01/01/0001 and 31/12/2999

Answer (score 0):

In case your dates attributes have taken different hour for the same day,you can do this :

```
where
trunc(active_date)
between to_date( ( NVL(:p_Active_Date, trunc(active_date)) ),'DD/MM/YYYY')
and  to_date( (NVL(:p_Close_Date, trunc(active_date) )  ),'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

I had one problem like that and the query did not show me the records in the range of the parameters which i had input.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WHERE
(:P_START_DATE IS NULL OR trunc(ACTIVE_DATE) > :P_START_DATE )
AND
(:P_END_DATE IS NULL OR trunc(ACTIVE_DATE) < :P_END_DATE )
```

Usually the Parameter is a date, and the table holds the start/end date though.

```
WHERE
(:P_ACTIVE_DATE IS NULL  
OR ((START_DATE IS NULL OR START_DATE <= :P_ACTIVE_DATE )
AND (END_DATE IS NULL OR END_DATE > :P_ACTIVE_DATE )))
```

Neither of those may suite your needs, but you get how the AND/OR work with the IS NULL.